# One-dimensional representation of $H^3$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, characters

Let denote by $H^3$ the 3-dimension Heisenberg group, i.e., the set $\mathbb C\times \mathbb R$ endowed with the group law
$$ (z,t)\cdot(w,s) =\left (z+w, \,t+s+\tfrac{1}{2}\Im m(z \bar{w})\right),$$
for $z=x+ i  y \in \mathbb C$ and $t\in \mathbb R$.
I would like to know why $$\chi_{w}(z,t)=e^{i\Re e(w.\bar{z})}; \qquad  w\in \mathbb C^{*}, (z,t)\in H^3,$$
is a one-dimensional representation of $H^3$ ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a composition of three maps: 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{H}^3 \ni (z,t) & \mapsto z \in \mathbb{C}, \\
\mathbb{C} \ni z & \mapsto \operatorname{Re}(w\bar{z}) \in \mathbb{R}, \\
\mathbb{R} \ni s & \mapsto e^{is} \in \mathbb{C}^*.
\end{align*}
Each of them is trivially checked to be a group homomorphism.

Comment: @ Michał Miśkiewicz,  Why it is one-dimensional ?

Comment: @Z.Alfata Any number $z \in \mathbb{C}$ can be associated with an endomorphism of the $1$-dimensional space $\mathbb{C}$ (multiplication by $z$). If $z \in \mathbb{C}^*$, this is also an isometry.

Comment: Correction: if $z \in \mathbb{C}^*$, this is an automorphism; if $z \in S^1$, this is an isometry.